# How to obtain Multi-turn conversations in Custom question answering

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have migrated from QNA maker to Custom question answering service for the bot project.

Now, I want to add the multi turn prompts functionality to display the related questions to the current query.

How can i achieve Multi-turn prompts with Custom question answering in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option called "Answer and prompts" under the answer section in custom question answer then click on "Add follow up prompts".

[image]

The popup will appear on the above step then you can add a multiturn feature similar to QnA Maker.

[image]

Comment: @ Rajeesh Menoth , Thanks for the response                                                                    Answer prompts are added. I have got the answer prompts response in Knowledge Base Answer. But not showing all the prompts in chat bot. How to use KnowledgeBaseAnswerPrompt to show the prompts

Comment: You need to use custom question answer SDK - Azure.AI.Language.QuestionAnswering. The existing QnA maker SDK did not work for this implementation.

Comment: @Aiswarya if the answer is helpful then you can accept it and it will helpful for others in the future.